# DataFrame combination

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I am working on a large multiIndex Dataframe that contains several indices e.g. `segment`, `period`, and `classification` as well as several columns with results e.g. `Results1`, `Results2`. The DataFrame `consolidated_df` is supposed to store all of my calculation results:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

segments = ['A', 'B', 'C']
periods = [1, 2]
classification = ['x', 'y']

index_constr = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [segments, periods, classification],
    names=['Segment', 'Period', 'Classification'])

consolidated_df = pd.DataFrame(np.nan, index=index_constr,
                                       columns=['Results1', 'Results2'])

print(consolidated_df)
```

The structure (of the large DataFrame) is as follows:

```
                               Results1  Results2
Segment Period Classification                    
A       1      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
        2      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
B       1      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
        2      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
C       1      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
        2      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
```

I am running a for loop over all my `segments` (`A`, `B` and `C`) to calculate the results (which are stored in the columns of the DataFrame using a separate function `calc_function`.

This function returns a DataFrame that has the exact same format as the consolidated DataFrame - except that it just reports one segment at a time (i.e. it is a slice of the consolidated DataFrame).

**Example:**

```
index_result = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['A'], periods, classification],
    names=['Segment', 'Period', 'Classification'])

result_calc = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,2), index=index_result, 
     columns=['Results1', 'Results2'])

print(result_calc)

                               Results1  Results2
Segment Period Classification                    
A       1      x              -1.568351  0.386250
               y               0.679170  1.552551
        2      x              -1.190928 -0.765319
               y               3.254929  1.436295
```

I tried using the below approach to store the results DataFrame in the consolidated one, but did not succeed:

```
for segment in segments:
#calc_function returns a DataFrame that has the same structure as consolidated_df
    consolidated_df.loc[idx[segment, :, :], :] = calc_function(segment)
```

Is there a way to easily integrate the smaller DataFrame into the consolidated one?

Comment: are all rows of `calc_function` the same? if so, maybe calculate it first, then `merge` it into the dataframe

Comment: The rows are exactly the same for all DataFrames returned by the calc_function (which in turn are subsets of the DataFrame that reports all results)

Comment: I'm trying to edit your example when constructing the index_result but not enough chars: it should read `[['A'], periods, classification]` (not `['A', periods, classification]`) because from_product uses lists.

Comment: If all are subsets, why not concatenate all segments: `pd.concat(segments)`?

Comment: Thanks, I think that would work as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example above, how about just `consolidated_df.ix['A'] = result_calc`?

(That's the same as `consolidated_df.ix['A', :, :] = result_calc`)

```
print(consolidated_df)

                               Results1  Results2
Segment Period Classification                    
A       1      x               1.290466  0.228978
               y              -0.276959  0.735192
        2      x               0.757339 -0.787502
               y              -0.609848  0.805773
B       1      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
        2      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
C       1      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
        2      x                    NaN       NaN
               y                    NaN       NaN
```